# Mozilla notification showing browser on click

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

I'm trying to make Mozilla FireFox plugin showing notification. Notifications are visible for Windows and even Mac I want the user to click the notification and open the web page, it sounds pretty simple.
But when adding observer and making window.open or gBroswer.addTab window is opened and tab is opened but in case FireFox is minimized when the notification is shown windows are opened in background and not visible to the user.

Tried to use Components.interfaces.nsIAlertsService and chrome://global/content/alerts/alert.xul they work the same from this perspective.
Is there a way to tell the browser to be top most and be visible to the user?

Comment: How can the user click on a notification in a minimized browser window anyway? I think you have to explain the problem better...

Comment: He means a bubble notification (hence the mention of nsIAlertsService).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this can be done. Firefox generally only supports switching focus between different browser windows when one of them is already focused (via `window.focus()`). To handle notifications the way you want it (and the way Thunderbird does it) one would need to call [SetForegroundWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows - there are only [two occasions](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/ident?i=SetForegroundWindow) in the Firefox code where this function is called. One is when a new Firefox process is started, the other is when one Firefox window is being minimized. Unfortunately, in this case neither can really be used and Thunderbird indeed uses custom code rather than existing XPCOM APIs to bring itself into foreground.